# Elasticsearch Char filter replace all the word of that line with regex

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I am trying to implement a character filter in elasticsearch that will do the task - find a word in a sentence [suppose the word is F], that sentence can be in a paragraph. it will add a prefix to all the following words [A] of [F] in the same sentence.

As an example: if the input text is
"It is not good and excellent. Hello World. i do not like it." will transform into "It is not ~good ~and ~excellent. Hello World. i do not ~like ~it."

As far i am doing i can replace the immediate next word in the same line after the word [F].

My filter looks like this :

```
      "char_filter" : {
            "post_negs" : {
                "type" : "pattern_replace",
                "pattern" : "\\b((?i:never|no|not))\\s+(\\w*\\.|\\?|!)",
                "replacement" : "$1 ~$2"
            }
       }
```

Now how i can achieve my goal using this. TIA.

Comment: Mind if I ask what the purpose of prefixing tilde's to the beginning of words, is?

Comment: nope. the purpose is to mark words negetivity. like if have a sentence like "he is not a good boy", it can't match a word good or boy. it will match not good.

Comment: So, I guess I'm failing to see what your question really is asking.  Is your filter not working, not constructed properly, or are you looking for a more robust regular expression?

Comment: probably you did not get me. My solution can replace only the immidiate next word in the string. But what i need is to replace all the word of that sentance to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there's a few inconsistencies that I see with your currently crafted regular expression and what you want your end result to be (referring to your example), but if I understand the gist of you're looking for, I think [this](http://bit.ly/21p4pMu) should work:

`\b(?!not?\b)(?!never\b)([\w-]+)` replace with `~$1`

Please note that the first lookahead will match both `not` and `no`.

Comment: still you are getting me wrong.  I don't want to replace all the word except the given with a ~prefixed.  I wanna do is

1. Find any word that match the given prefix.
2. Add ~ after all the word of that given word **Until the line ends** Means.

--- **
"It is not good and excellent. Hello World. i do not no like it never note." **
will turn into
**"It is not ~good ~and ~excellent. Hello World. i do not ~no ~like ~it ~never ~note." **

Comment: Is each word getting tokenized?  If so, then you may be seeking something that may not be possible; at least with one application of a regular expression.